# why does passing char[] not work, but (deprecated conversion) char* does?

Tags: c++

I cannot explain myself the reason for the following behaviour. I initialize two pieces of text, one as char*, the other as char[] and put them into a structure. Both appear fine in the structure, but back in main, the second one is lost, and the first gives me a compiler warning which i understand (deprecated conversion from string constant to char*).

This is the first question I ask here, and I apologize for anything done wrong. And yes, I tried to search, but related to char* and char[], there appear a lot of Q&A, none I found similar to the nested problem I am having.

From the attached code I get the output:

```
get_struct: 5 test test2
main: 5 test
```

(the test2 at the end missing)

So the code:

```
    #include <iostream> 

    typedef struct {
        double a_double;
        char* a_char1;
        char* a_char2;
    } testStruct;

    testStruct make_struct(double d, char* c1, char* c2) {          
        testStruct t;

        t.a_double = d;
        t.a_char1 = c1;
        t.a_char2 = c2;

        return t;
    }

    void get_struct(testStruct &t) {    
        char* test_char1 = "test";
        char test_char2[] = "test2";
        double test_double = 5;

        t = make_struct(test_double, test_char1, test_char2);

        std::cout << "get_struct: " << t.a_double << " " 
            << t.a_char1 << " " << t.a_char2  << std::endl;
    }

    int main() {
        testStruct t;
        get_struct(t);
        std::cout << "main: " << t.a_double << " " 
            << t.a_char1 << " " << t.a_char2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What about not using `char*` or `char[]` at all? ;-)

Comment: I imagine (I haven't coded in C++ since 2003-ish) that when `get_struct` returns its local variables are potentially lost/freed.

Comment: If you are using C++ then use std::string, which is @stefan's point

Comment: Actually both usages will cause undefined behavior as you are filling a struct using local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in that you store pointers to local variables in the structure.

In the case of the `test_char2` array, it no longer exists once the `get_struct` function returns. This means that the pointer `a_char2` no longer points to a valid string, and dereferencing this pointer is undefined behavior.

The reason the first pointer works, is because it doesn't point to a local variable, it points to a string literal, and those are stored elsewhere in memory.

When coding in C++, there is no longer a reason to use pointers or arrays for string, instead use the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the string literal is always stored elsewhere (statically)? Or is that just how most/all compilers do it?

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Most compilers used to put string literals in the code segment, as it's read-only. I don't know if modern compilers still do that. I also don't have the C++ specification in front of me right now, and neither any ABI specification, so I can't really say if it's *guaranteed* to be stored anywhere. All I can say is that they are never stored on the stack like local variables.

Comment: Cool and thanks. I know roughly how it works with gcc and other modern compilers, but I've just had to use some really old ones for embedded stuff too. I just like to know in case it ever seems like it might save a copy for these embedded systems. If it *can't* be on the stack, then it's a safe bet it's some kind of static memory. Thanks.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: String literals are guaranteed to have static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* test_char1 = "test";
```

This creates a pointer to a string literal. String literals are `const` but, for historical reasons, the language allows the pointer to be non-`const`; however, this is deprecated, hence the warning. If you attempt to modify the string, then you'll get undefined behaviour.

```
char test_char2[] = "test2";
```

This creates a local array, initialised by copying a string literal. It is not `const`, so you can modify it if you like. But once the function returns, this is destroyed, so your structure ends up with a *dangling pointer* to invalid memory. That is why you get undefined behaviour when you try to print it in `main`.

Two pieces of advice:

- Don't use C-style character arrays and pointers to represent strings; use `std::string`. That manages memory for you, avoiding the lifetime issues you're encountering here.
- If you really want to mess around with arrays and pointers, use `const char*` unless you actually need to modify it. Otherwise, it's difficult to work with string literals.

Comment: To clarify a little, `char test_char2[] = "test2";` turns into `char test_char2[6] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '2', '\0'};`

Answer (score 1):

When assigning a string literal to a local `char[]`-variable, that storage is allocated locally.

Exporting that pointer from that scope violates the (automatic) storage duration constraints of the local variable and accessing the memory behind the pointer is undefined behaviour.

In contrast, when assigning to `char*`, a pointer to a statically allocated string is created and no copying to local storage takes place. Thus, the pointer remains valid outside that scope.